# Add distinct element from date list and coountry_list to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to create out of the 2 lists below one dataframe showing for a given date one country that is in the country_list

```
date_list = ['2020-05-01','2020-05-02','2020-05-03','2020-05-04']

country_list = ['Germany','England']
```

Output_DF

```
date        country
2020-05-01  Germany
2020-05-01  England
2020-05-02  Germany
2020-05-02  England
2020-05-03  Germany
2020-05-03  England
2020-05-04  Germany
2020-05-04  England
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the process you want is the "cartesian product" of 2 lists. You can use python's built-in library `itertools.product` to achieve this, and then construct a `DataFrame`:

```
import itertools
data = itertools.product(date_list, country_list)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["date", "country"])

print(df)
         date  country
0  2020-05-01  Germany
1  2020-05-01  England
2  2020-05-02  Germany
3  2020-05-02  England
4  2020-05-03  Germany
5  2020-05-03  England
6  2020-05-04  Germany
7  2020-05-04  England
```

Comment: nice and simple solution! :)

Answer (score 1):

A simple list comprehension is enough:

```
import pandas as pd

date_list = ['2020-05-01', '2020-05-02', '2020-05-03', '2020-05-04']
country_list = ['Germany', 'England']

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[date, country] for date in date_list for country in country_list],
                  columns=["dates", "countries"])

print(df)
```

As an alternative use [MultiIndex.from_product](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
import pandas as pd

date_list = ['2020-05-01','2020-05-02','2020-05-03','2020-05-04']

country_list = ['Germany','England']

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([date_list, country_list], names=["dates", "countries"])

df = index.to_frame(index=False)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
        dates countries
0  2020-05-01   Germany
1  2020-05-01   England
2  2020-05-02   Germany
3  2020-05-02   England
4  2020-05-03   Germany
5  2020-05-03   England
6  2020-05-04   Germany
7  2020-05-04   England
```

Comment: You can call `index.to_frame(index=False)` instead of constructing a new `DataFrame` and using `reset_index()`

Comment: Added to the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
        [sorted(date_list * 2), country_list * 4], 
        index=['dates', 'countries']).T

    dates   countries
0   2020-05-01  Germany
1   2020-05-01  England
2   2020-05-02  Germany
3   2020-05-02  England
4   2020-05-03  Germany
5   2020-05-03  England
6   2020-05-04  Germany
7   2020-05-04  England
```